# How to add ability to scale your skills in your resume/CV

Tags: gimp, template-design, resume

I would like to implement a skills bar chart into a resume template. I am using Gimp for this project and am trying to find ways to implement this feature. Example below. [image: resume example]

Comment: 1) I highly recommend you do NOT put these ratings on your resume. At best it means nothing because you're self evaluating and at worst it makes you look unqualified if you put a lower rating. 2) What part are you getting stuck on??

Comment: 1. Since this is a template it's a must for me to put these scale ratings. I understand your reasoning in not putting them but it's a must for me. 2. I need to find a way to implement this feature, that's what I'm stuck on. Questions I've asked myself is if I'd need Javascript for this and if so, how would the user scale himself.

Comment: Better check the spelling. *"Presonal skills"*?, *"After effet"*?

Comment: Are you asking how to draw the graphics?  If so, GIMP wouldn't be my first choice. Use a vector image editor like inkscape instead. You can import the SVG into GIMP.

Comment: It's more on how can the user show his skill set using the scale,  how can the user edit the scale.

Comment: If you are using GIMP for a resume... that is a bad indicator for your graphic design skills.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way to do this would be to do it as text/type: just **use a row of slashes ( / ) or vertical lines ( | )**, probably in bold, and then just **change the color of the type** for how high you would rank yourself in those skills.

EDIT: I am not really familiar with GIMP, but depending on its type capabilities, you can play around with how the type looks by adjusting kerning, or adding a contour to the type to make it look even thicker than just bold.

IMHO, I would not do this kind of thing in GIMP in the first place, but rather use a proper DTP (desktop publishing) software like InDesign (which I understand is expensive) or Scribus (which is freeware, https://www.scribus.net/). Both of these have a bit of a learning curve, but in my opinion it's worth it.

Answer (score 4):

For each bar, make a layer group with:

- the empty bar as a row a grey dashes over a transparent background
- above it, a transparent layer set in `Color` mode

Then paint the required color on the top layer of the group (it doesn't even need to be accurate)

[image]